# How much is deployed while deploying a specific firebase cloud function?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

If I have a firebase cloud function like this:

```
exports.exampleFunction = function (admin, envKey) {
  return functions..https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    doSomething(req)
  }
}
```

And I modify the `doSomething` function and deploy `exampleFunction` with:

```
firebase deploy --only functions:exampleFunction
```

Will the modifications to `doSomething` be included in the deployment? This is a trivial example - but more generally - does Firebase track the dependencies of a function when it is deployed? Or do I need to deploy all functions in order to push modifications to dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase has no way to introspect the workings of your code to understand what has changed or hasn't, so every deploy deploys all files in the functions directory to be rebuilt. Using the `--only` flag controls which functions will actually be updated, but the same source code is used to build and deploy each function regardless of flags.